# Geodesic distance, Euclidean distance and curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature, submanifold

Consider a Riemann manifold $\mathcal{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Given two points $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathcal{X}$, denote with $d_g (\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ the geodesic distance between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$. That is, $ d_g (\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ denotes the length of a geodesic $\gamma\colon [0, 1]\rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ with endpoints $\gamma(0) = \mathbf{x}$ and $\gamma(1) = \mathbf{y}$.

Denote with $\tau \colon \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function, such that $\tau(\mathbf{x})$ is the curvature of of the manifold $\mathcal{X}$ at a point $\mathbf{x}$. Can we upper-bound the Euclidean distance $\| \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \|_2$, in terms of $d_g (\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ and $\tau$?

Comment: Obviously the Euclidean distance is bounded above by the geodesic distance; does that not suit your purposes?

Comment: well, is it possible to have a more accurate estimate? I think that the curvature might play a role.

Comment: Briefly, I think it is not possible: Take a circular arc $C$ as close to a line as you like, and extend it to a ribbon with large principal curvature in the direction perpendicular to $C$. We can easily arrange that $C$ is a geodesic, but the Gaussian curvature along $C$ is arbitrarily large (positive or negative, as you prefer) in absolute value.

Comment: Additionally, what do you mean by curvature here? Do you mean the scalar curvature? Otherwise, it is not a real-valued function but a tensor.

Comment: Yes, I mean the scalar curvature. @AndrewD.Hwang, I see your point, but I think that in your example the length of $C$ also changes arbitrarily, right? I agree with you that it is not possible to upper-bound the Euclidean distance in terms of $\tau$, but what I'm looking for is a bound in terms of both $\tau$ and $d_g(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$.